# How to add subject in tranctional email template for magento 2 version

Tags: magento2

I create below but not idea how to add custom subject in this code

```
$transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($emailTemplateId)
                      ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $storeId])
                        ->setTemplateVars($templateParams)
                       ->setFrom(['name' => $senderEmailName, 'email' => $senderEmail])
                        ->addTo($email)
                       ->getTransport();
                $transport->sendMessage();
```

For Magento 1 we use add line:-

```
->setTemplateSubject($mailSubject)
```

Answer (score 1):

As it has already been answered, you do set it within the template via

```
<!--@subject [...] @-->
```

You can read it out then *within* the template by accessing the following template variable:

```
{{var this.getSubject()}}
```

If you for example use the `trans` directive to create the subject, this will return the translated subject.

Setting the subject for the message then is transparently done when the **TransportBuilder** prepares the message (`\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder::prepareMessage`).

So technically, as long as you make use of the email-templates (which is recommended, see `email_templates.xml` files for reference) this is how the subject is handled.

In your code this happens already within the call to

```
->getTransport();
```

If the subject is empty, set it in the template first.

---

References:

- [Magento 2: How to declare a custom email template for your module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/114214/4115) (Stackexchange)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the subject in the email template header

```
<!--@subject This is subject @-->
```